# Rails unit test functional and underscored module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I start unit test implementation in my REST Api application.
I use [versionist gem](https://github.com/bploetz/versionist).

So, I have a class named like this : `Api::V0_1_0::TestController`

```ruby
class Api::V0_1_0::TestController < Api::V0_1_0::BaseController

  def test
    respond_with({
      :message => "done"
    })
  end

end
```

`routes.rb` (without all routes, but just the necessary):

```ruby
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ApiVersions
  #
  scope :module => "api",
        :defaults => {:format => "json"} do

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # V0.1.0
    # Default version
    #
    api_version :module => "V0__1__0",
                :header => "X-Version", :value => "0.1.0" do

      # Test controller
      get "/test" => "test#test"
    end
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # V0.1.1
    # Default version
    #
    api_version :module => "V0__1__1",
                :header => "X-Version", :value => "0.1.1" do

      # Test Controller
      get "/test" => "test#test"

  end
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ActiveAdmin routes
  #
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


end
```

Functional test file :

```ruby
class Api::V0_1_0::TestControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "should get test" do
    get :test
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

When I launch `rake test:functionals`.
I have this error :

> No route matches {:controller=>"api/v0_1_0/test", :action=>"test"}

And when I launch `rake routes`, I have :

```
test GET  /test(.:format)   {:format=>"json", :controller=>"api/V0__1__0/test", :action=>"test"}
```

With double underscore for `V0__1__0` and not `V0_1_0`.

I don't know how resolve this problem.

EDIT: I have add `routes.rb`.

NOTE: I've also post an issue here : https://github.com/bploetz/versionist/issues/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails functional tests (ActionController::TestCase) are for testing controller action methods in isolation. They do not go through the full Rails stack, specifically the Rails dispatcher code path, which is where versionist hooks in to do it's thing.

If you want to test your versioned API routes which rely on the HTTP header strategy, use integration tests (ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest) or request specs if you're using rspec.

```
require 'test_helper'

class Api::V0_1_0::TestControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should get test" do
    get '/test', nil, {"X-Version" => "0.1.0"}
    assert_response :success
    assert_equal @response.body, "0.1.0"
  end
end
```

Versionist 0.2.0 added integration tests/request specs to the components created by it's generators (https://github.com/bploetz/versionist/issues/11).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the link you provided, can you do something like this?

```
api_version :module => "V0__1__0",
            :path => "/V0_1_0",
            :header => "X-Version", :value => "0.1.0" do
```

Or

```
get "/test" => "test#test", :controller => "api/V0_1_0/test"
```

Comment: Yes, this line do a scope, like :
`scope :module => "v0__1__0"`. (cf: https://github.com/bploetz/versionist)

Comment: I've updated the answer to see if anything else can be changed.

Comment: The second option can be run. But in the gem README it's write : "If you wish to simply replace dots with underscores, you'll need to use two underscores (i.e. __) in the module name passed to api_version to work around a quirk in Rails' inflector."